# Represent an arbitrary 2x2 matrix entries using sines and cosines

Tags: matrices

I'm reading Graphics with Mathematica, Fractals, Julia Sets, Patterns, and Natural Forms, by Chonat Getz and Janet Helmstedt. There is a statement: Any matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers, can be written in the form $\begin{bmatrix}r\cos\theta&-s\sin\phi\\r\sin\theta&s\cos\phi\end{bmatrix}$, where $r$, $s$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ are real numbers. I've been trying to come up with a way of proving this, also searching online, but have not come up with a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: How searchable is this title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the vector $(a, c)^T$, we find $r$, $\theta$ such that

$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r\cos \theta \\ r\sin \theta \end{pmatrix} \tag{1}$

as follows:  set

$r = \sqrt{a^2 + c^2}; \tag{1}$

then there is a unique $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ such that

$a = r\cos \theta \tag{2}$

and

$c = r \sin \theta; \tag{3}$

indeed, if $a \ne 0$ take

$\tan \theta = \dfrac{c}{a}; \tag{4}$

if $c \ne 0$, take

$\cot \theta = \dfrac{a}{c}; \tag{5}$

if $a = c = 0$, take $\theta$ arbitrarily.

We can find $s$ and $\phi$ corresponding to $b$ and $d$ similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider polar coordinate of $(a,c)$.

Can you solve for $r$ and $\theta$?

Similarly consider polar coordinate for $(d,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just polar coordinates: any point in the plane $(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)$ for suitable $r$ and $t$. This is just applying this principle
to the two points $(a,c)$ and $(d,-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can take $r = \sqrt{a^2 + c^2}$ and $s = \sqrt{b^2 + d^2}$.